# Scheduled email in php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a program written in php/html where the user will input a job then after submit, will notify the admin and other users through email. What I wanted is to have a scheduled email where it will notify the admin/users that the job has not yet been done after 12 hrs. I've read about cronjob or cron tab but I don't understand hoe to use it well. Is there another way to do it using phpmailer and not crontab?

Comment: you cant do it with phpmailer alone, you need something that can run code periodically, that's where cron comes in.

Answer (score -1):

yes and no.

PHP by its nature is a stateless script that runs when a user or service requests a url.

The php script runs, does it stuff and then ends, normally there is relatively short timeout either in the PHP config or on the webserver, so you cant have a script running in the background waiting for a specific time to send out your email.

In your situation, you would create a cron job (or a scheduled task on windows) this task/job generally runs on the webserver (although is doesn't have to), the task will load a php script, either as a command or via wget.

So set the task to start at the intervals you require, it will envoke the PHP script, send the emails or what ever you want it to do then the php script will end, ready to run on the next schedule.